# Как сделать не обязательную для заполнения форму?

Tags: html, django

у меня есть checkbox, который  хочу сделать не обязательным к заполнению, как это можно реализовать. На сколько я понял аргумент `required` идет к форме по умолчанию. Я пытался передать ему параметр false в самой форме:

```
CheckBox = forms.CharField(

        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
            attrs={'type': 'checkbox', 'class': 'contaner__form__BlokcCheckBox_checkbox', 'id': 'checkbox', 'required': 'false'}
        )

    )
```

Также попробовал так:

```
CheckBox = forms.CharField(

        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
            attrs={'type': 'checkbox', 'class': 'contaner__form__BlokcCheckBox_checkbox', 'id': 'checkbox',}
        ),
       required=False
    )
```

Попытался передать напрямую к input:

```
<input type="checkbox" required="false">
```

Но тон также проигнорировался. Поэтому обратился с вопросом к вам.

Comment: по идее добавленый в класс формы required=False + в модели куда будете сохранять форму должно стоять null=True

Comment: Здесь есть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205908/django-modelform-not-required-field  | invoice = forms.BooleanField(
    widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'checkboxInvoice'}),
    required=False
)

Comment: cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

Answer (score 0):

И так отвечаю на вопрос благодаря комментариям.
Предположим, что вам нужно сделать не обязательным поле adrees в вашей форме.

Что нужно сделать:
В классе вашей модели нужно прописать:

Если ваша версия Django < 1.8:

```
class My_Form(ModelForm):

    address = forms.CharField(required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = My_Class
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name' , 'address')
```

Если версия Django  > 1.8:

```
class My_Form(ModelForm):

    address = forms.CharField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = My_Class
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name' , 'address')
```

Также нужно прописать `required=False` в классе вашей формы:

```
class My_form(forms.Form):

    address = forms.CharField(


        required=False,


        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
            attrs={'type': 'text', 'class': 'your_class'}
        )

    )
```

Ответ частично взят отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205908/django-modelform-not-required-field